# Excel VBA run-time error 1004 which I can't identify

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

This is my code:

```
Sub VerticalLoop()

Dim i As Integer

Range("VerticalLoop").Activate

i = 1

Do While i <= Range("VerticalLoop").Rows.Count

ActiveCell.Value = i
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
i = i + 1

  Loop



 End Sub
```

For some reason I can't run this. When I press F8, the error pops up when I reach the line "i=1", so I don't know exactly what I did wrong.

Comment: Are you certain that this is failing on the line i=1 ? What is the error description? Normally for 1004, it's in the format xx method of yy class failed. For example, if the named range doesn't exist, you would get this error number with the description "Activate method of Range class failed" on the Activate line. I can't think of a reason to get this error on the i=1 line.

Comment: @Jane I did this in a sheet, when I copy and pasted the code to a module it worked flawlessly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will fail if the Sheet containing the Defined Name has not been activated first!

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line

```
Range("VerticalLoop").Activate
```

The error is probably a typo in the name of the range. Are you sure it isn't supposed to be "Vertical_Loop" (with the underscore)?

On the other hand, Gary's Student is correct that a '1004' error could be triggered by trying to activate a range in an inactive sheet. The error message itself (and not just the error number) can tell you more about the exact source of the error. Alternatively, you could break that line into two lines like thus:

```
Dim VLoop As Range
Set VLoop = Range("VericalLoop")
VLoop.Activate
```

If the Set VLoop line throws the error then the problem is with your name. If the second line throws the error then then problem is with what is active.

As an added benefit -- once you debug this error you now have a useful range variable allowing you to use expressions like VLoop.Rows.Count